# JQuery datetime picker showing console errors

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery function datetime picker for a web application

i have the JS Library for this included in my page, and i have added this function at the botton of the .js file

```
function datetime_picker(t) {
    if($(t).val() == "") {
        var dt = new Date();

        var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

        var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var output = dt.getFullYear() + '-' + (month<10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day<10 ? '0' : '') + day;

        var datetime = output + ' ' + time

        $(t).val(datetime);
    }

    $(t).datetimepicker({
        step:1, 
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10']
    });
}
```

i am then using this in my text inputs to call the function:

```
<input type="text" name="date_paid" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" onclick="date_picker(this);" readonly="readonly" />
```

its adding the current date/time into the text input on the first click which is fine, however on the second click it should open up the calendar popup.

when looking in the console, i am receiving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on this line:

```
$(t).datetimepicker({
```

Comment: what is the value of `t` and have you included the script for the `datatimepicker` plugin?

Comment: datetimepicker is not a predifined function in jquery lib, so maybe it's an external plug-in that you forgot to include ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan second line of my question "i have the JS Library for this included in my page" - the value of t would be what it says in the text input - (this) - meaning the text input

Comment: in jQuery UI there is only datepicker, no datetimepicker (you can do also pick datetime, not only date, depends on configuration). Since I do not know which jQuery Plugin you use, check on this.

Comment: @Charles is the path to it correct?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have checked the path in the source code and thats okay

Comment: @mondjunge i have this code from the JQuery website (http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)